# Batch .pdf files generation using seam <p:document>

Tags: xhtml, pdf-generation, seam

I want to generate a big pdf file using Seam.

Seam have .xhtml support for pdf generation with  tag but this facility only work when there is a browser interaction.

I didn't find any way to use this seam pdf facilities as a background/batch way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution here.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/180380#comment24174

And a jira here to make it easier.  But since nothing done since 2008 might not be done :)
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-2613

Comment: I will definitely go for a solution like jasper because the seam one seems too tricky